# Are console games locked to a certain region?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3, region-lock

I'm going on a vacation from Europe to the US and was planning of bringing along some Xbox360 or PS3 games, but now I'm curious if they will be compatible with my European Xbox.

In that past there would be a clear difference between NTSC and PAL games, but is this still the case with the current gen of consoles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This greatly depends on the game itself. Certain versions of games are compatible with other kinds, some aren't.

Here's a list for the Xbox 360: [Region Free Xbox 360 Games](http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Region_Free_Xbox_360_Games)

The PS3 has no such restrictions, but there are [reports](http://www.joystiq.com/2007/05/07/ps3-is-region-free-but-theres-a-hi-def-catch/) of issues with SD televisions.

Comment: I didn't know that there were region free XBox 360 games, but region control makes me mad because they lied to us about it. :-p